# Typescript: why does Partial interface not accept additional fields?

Tags: typescript

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;  
}

let user: Partial<User> = {name: 'John', address: '123 Main st.'}
```

So typescript will complain about `address` does not exist in interface `User`.
My understanding is that as long as `Partial<User>` is a subset of the right side object, it should be a valid coercion. How to understand it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called **Excess Property Checking**

From typescript documentation (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks):

> ... TypeScript takes the stance that there’s probably a bug in this code. Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error.
>
> Getting around these checks is actually really simple. The easiest method is to just use a type assertion:

Comment: You may want to link to the [specific section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) and use the phrase "excess property checking".

Answer (score 1):

@ABOS

What `Partial<User>` is doing for you there is making the User interface's properties optional.

Similar to this,

```
interface User {
   name?: string;
   age?: number;
}
```

I think what you would really want to do is further extend your User interface,

```
interface User {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}


interface Mod extends User {
    address: string;
}

// this here then makes age from the user interface optional but also allows 
// you to now have the address property.

let user: Partial<Mod> = {name: "John", address: "123 Main st."};
```

Or you can make it more robust by then implementing your interface/s in a class like so.

```
class Users implements Mod {
    address: string;
    name: string;
    age: number;

    // we can make the address and age defaulted values if not provided
    constructor(name: string, address: string = "", age: number = 0) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

let user: Mod = new Users("John");

console.log(user.name);     // "John"
console.log(user.address);  // ""
console.log(user.age);      // 0
```